# Generate an array with offset of structure fields

Tags: c, struct

I am interested in generating an array with offset of structure fields.

```
struct B
{
  int pig[100];
  bool donkey[100];
}

struct A
{
   int ant[100];
   bool cat[38];
   struct B dog[78];
}

main ()
{
   int offset[100+38+78] /* ant offsets + cat offsets + dog offsets */
   /* How do I fill up these offset array to fill in with offsets of ant, cat, dog */
}

Output should be something like:
offset[0] = 0;
offset[1] = 4;
......
......
offset[99]= 4*99;
.......
offset[100+38+78-1] = ? ;
```

I know C doesn't support reflection and we can make use of X_MACROS to some extent, but my structures are really complex. I would like to kickstart with basic simple structure that I had posted in this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the addresses of the array elements to `char *` and then subtract the address of the structure.

```
struct A a;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    offset[i] = (char*)&a.ant[i] - (char*)&a;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 38; i++) {
    offset[100 + i] = (char*)&a.cat[i] - (char*)&a;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 78; i++) {
    offset[100 + 38 + i] = (char*)&a.dog[i] - (char*)&a;
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. That helps. Just out of box question, is there a way to get the offset of the field by passing the structure variable as an argument. For instance Input : cat[37]: offset of cat[37] is XXXX ?

Comment: You could use `(char *)&a.cat[37] - char(*)&a`

Comment: Thanks a lot again. Is there a way to get the offset of the field pig[2] relative to the struct A and not using struct B information at all, something like, offsetof ( struct A, pig[2] ) is ??

Comment: That doesn't make sense. There are multiple B elements in A, so you need to provide the index, e.g. `a.dog[10].pig[2]`